# What's limited size of Video file when directly play on Blackberry Programming?

Tags: blackberry, video-streaming

This is my source :

```
public MyScreen() {
    // Set the displayed title of the screen
    setTitle("MyTitle");
    // URL of video file about 200KB size
    String url = "http://a1408.g.akamai.net/5/1408/1388/2005110405/1a1a1ad948be278cff2d96046ad90768d848b41947aa1986/sample_mpeg4.mp4";

    BrowserSession browserSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
    browserSession.displayPage(url);
    browserSession.showBrowser();

}
```

When I changed another URL of video file -- URL = "http://myServer/test.mp4" (this file about 2M size ) so my Apps can not run video file... It has one error popup appear on my screen. This is error content :

```
The item you selected can not displayed. Do you want to save or cancel?
```

Why appear this error . I think file size is reason of this error( may be@@)...

If you know that. please help me...
I need to your support @@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specified url "http://a1408.g.akamai.net/5/1408/1388/2005110405/1a1a1ad948be278cff2d96046ad90768d848b41947aa1986/sample_mpeg4.mp4"
is not working in mozilla also for streaming

Understand some process for browser

when you provide request to server it will give reply according to your user agent and request

if the reply content is supported by browser then it will display no problem.

if browser not support that content then it will offer  us to "save"

you can save that item then you can open.

for example blackberry browser does not support .pdf files till now. so if you request to open any pdf file in browser it wont open. that browser offer us to save

same this way some of the contents not supported by browser